# Using simple_form in Rails 4, trying to pass data attributes to an input_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using simple_form in Rails 4, and I was using an input that I then passed data attributes to like so:

```
<%= f.input :url, :input_html => {"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => "My tooltip"} %>
```

and it worked as expected, creating tags like:

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="My tooltip">
```

Now, however, I need to use simple_form's `input_field` so I can have more control over the display, but it doesn't seem to accept the input_html argument. My code looks like:

```
<%= f.input_field :url, :input_html => {"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => "My tooltip"} %>
```

and it results in:

```
<input html="{:data=>{&quot;data-toggle&quot;=>&quot;tooltip&quot;, :title=>&quot;My tooltip&quot;}}">
```

Which is clearly suboptimal (I stripped other irrelevant properties and attributes to simplify).  Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for [SimpleForm::FormBuilder#input_field](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L134), it appears that all options passed in are treated as if they were under `:input_html`.

Try removing `:input_html` and just passing the options directly:

```
<%= f.input_field :url, "data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => "My tooltip" %>
```

Comment: Yep, this works.  I actually did read the code, but still didn't quite get how the attributes should be passed (I had tried `:data-toggle => "tooltip" `, which doesn't work.)